exec.Command hangs when next scripts are having nohup command to start the services
Using the following code to run the given commands or scripts:
var shell, shellArg string
if runtime.GOOS == "windows" {
    shell = "powershell.exe"
    shellArg = "-Command"
    // Modify the command to ensure it fails on any error
    command = fmt.Sprintf("try { %s } catch { exit 1 }", command)
} else {
    shell = "/bin/sh"
    shellArg = "-c"
    // Modify the command to use 'set -e' to ensure it fails on any error
    command = fmt.Sprintf("set -e; %s", command)
}

cmd := exec.Command(shell, shellArg, command)

When I execute a command or normal scripts it works like charm. But in a specific case it's getting hung.
I have a bash script main.sh which controls the another bash script. In the next bash script services.sh I am using the below command to start the WebLogic services:
nohup ./startService.sh &

When I run main.sh script using Go, I can see it starts the services as coded in the services.sh but Go cmd.exec is coming out though main.sh process is completed. If the main.sh is still running then it makes sense for Go to hang and my worry is even though main.sh is completed why Go exec.command is hung?
Below is the complete script of how am handling it right now
// Capture stdout and stderr
var stdout, stderr bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stdout = &stdout
cmd.Stderr = &stderr

Logger.Printf("Executing command: %s", strings.Join(cmd.Args, " "))

// // Run the command
// err := cmd.Run()

// Run the command
if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
    result.Stderr = fmt.Sprintf("Failed to start command: %v", err)
    result.ExitCode = 1
    return result
}

done := make(chan error)
go func() {
    done <- cmd.Wait()
}()

select {
case err := <-done:
    // Command completed
    fmt.Println("Command Completed")
    if err != nil {
        if exitError, ok := err.(*exec.ExitError); ok {
            result.ExitCode = exitError.ExitCode()
        } else {
            result.ExitCode = 1 // Generic error code if not an ExitError
        }
        result.Stderr = stderr.String()
    } else {
        result.ExitCode = 0 // Success
        result.Stdout = stdout.String()
        result.Stderr = stderr.String()
    }
case <-time.After(864000 * time.Second): // Adjust the timeout as necessary
    // Command timed out
    if err := cmd.Process.Kill(); err != nil {
        result.Stderr = fmt.Sprintf("Failed to kill process: %v", err)
        result.ExitCode = 1
        return result
    }
    result.Stderr = "Command timed out"
    result.ExitCode = 1
    return result
}

result.Stdout = stdout.String()
result.Stderr = stderr.String()

Using the same way of executing if I have the nohup command as below then its working
nohup ./startService.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &

I suspect that golang is holding because nohup keeps printing the message on stdout and its not getting closed. Not sure exactly what is happening behind

You didn't provide the code for how you're executing the command. Based on your description, I'm assuming you're using cmd.Run() or cmd.Output() to execute the command, which waits until the process exits before returning.
Instead, you need to use cmd.Start(), which starts the process in the background and returns immediately. If you need the output, you can use cmd.StdoutPipe() and/or cmd.StderrPipe() to get it as an io.Reader.

Updated the question section with more details
